# How "Use Hardware Acceleration" option in Chrome affect performance?

Tags: google-chrome, hardware-acceleration

Suddenly Chrome was running extremely slow on my Ubuntu machine. I tried updating to the latest version. But didn't work. Just turning Hardware Acceleration off fixed the problem. Because the slowness happened suddenly don't know whether the option was always on, or did it turn on due to some reason.

Great some one can explain what is really happening with this "Hardware Acceleration" thing.

Comment: Chrome updates come with the usual updates. Was the "suddenly" after some system update? Also please [edit] and post the hardware specs (graphics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously hardware acceleration works great when you have a decent graphics processor. But if for some reason that GPU isn't working so great then hardware acceleration suffers in browsers. It's why when users complain about performance that involves GPU acceleration. First quick fix is turn off the HA setting. Of course the real solution is determining why the GPU isn't doing a good job, or is it simply a matter its barely acceptable to handle the tasks. In my experience most browsers use hardware acceleration by default and rarely have I seen a hardware setup that disables this. I always say use the settings that work the best.

Comment: Thanks. So I think the problem might be because It was a Parallels VM.